# Which partition is mounted to where?

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition

How can we check the mount points for partitions listed in `/dev/sd*`? For example, I would like know if the partition for my home is `/dev/sda4`.

Answer (score 26):

Another approach is with [findmnt](http://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt):

```
findmnt /dev/sda4
```

...to get mountpoint from dev. Or vice-versa:

```
findmnt /home
```

Comment: any command option that would make it return only the dev or mountpoint, so that it can be directly piped into other commands?

Comment: @Matan use the `-n|-noheadings` and `-o|--output` options. for mount point to dev translation: `findmnt -no SOURCE /mount/point`. for dev to mount point translation: `findmnt -no TARGET`. available output columns are listed at `findmnt -h`.

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

- `mount` for a list of all mounted filesystems and mount options for each of them;
- `lsblk` for a tree of block devices, size and mount point (if mounted);
- `df` for a list of mounted block devices, size, used space, available space and mount point.

Comment: `lsblk` is linux specific?

Comment: Yes, `util-linux` package.

Comment: @Miline /dev/sd\* to refer to disks and partitions is Linux-specific as well. Other Unix-like systems solve the same problem but have different naming conventions.

Comment: `lsblk` was exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You're actually asking two questions. The easiest thing to do if you want to know where your home is:

```
cd
df -h .
```

Or

```
df -h $HOME
```

Where is /tmp mounted?

```
df -h /tmp
```

...etc.

If you want to know what is mounted on a certain device,

```
mount | grep ^/dev/sda1
```

(for example). Or

```
mount | grep ^/dev/sd
```

to see all the sd's.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you're after. If you want to check which of the partitions in `/dev/sd*` has a default mountpoint and what that mountpoint is, you could do

```
for part in /dev/sd*; do grep -w "$part" /etc/fstab | awk '{print $1,$2}; done
```

However, on most modern systems, partitions are mounted by UUID and not dev name, so a better approach<sup>1</sup> would be:

```
for uuid in /dev/disk/by-uuid/*; do 
    mpoint=$(grep "$(basename $uuid)" /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}')
    [ -n "$mpoint" ]  && echo  "$(basename $(readlink $uuid)) : $mpoint"; 
done
```

On my system, for example, that returns:

```
sda3 : swap
sda1 : /
sda2 : /home
sdc1 : /mnt/bigboy
sdb3 : /mnt/movies
sdb1 : /winblows
```

You could also extend that to report those partitions with no default mount point:

```
for uuid in /dev/disk/by-uuid/*; do 
    dev=$(basename $(readlink $uuid))
    mpoint=$(grep "$dev" /etc/fstab | awk '{print $2}')
    if [ -n "$mpoint" ]; then
      echo  "$dev : $mpoint"; 
    else
      echo "$dev : No mountpoint"
    fi
done
```

---

If you want to find out the partition of a given directory, for example `~/`, you can use `df`:

```
$ df /home/
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      442047744 266441120 153128800  64% /home
```

Or, to get the device name only (note that the `--output` flag is not POSIX):

```
 $ df --output=source /home/ | tail -n1
 /dev/sda2
```

---

To get a list of currently mounted partitions and their mountpoints:

```
mount | awk '/^\/dev/{print $1,$3}'
```

---

Finally, a very useful command is `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  29.3G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0 428.4G  0 part /home
└─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   1.4T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   9.8G  0 part /winblows
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   1.2T  0 part /mnt/movies
├─sdb5   8:21   0  46.6G  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0    14G  0 part 
├─sdb7   8:23   0 117.4G  0 part 
└─sdb8   8:24   0   2.3G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/bigboy
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>An even better approach is `findmnt` but I'd never heard of that before reading [@taliezin's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192280/22222).</sub>

Comment: I guess the mention of /etc/fstab is good, but your loops over it seem needlessly complex.  Also, /proc/mounts is always up-to-date, but /etc/fstab doesn't necessarily match.  The first script could be `awk '/^[^#]*\/dev\// {print $1, $2 }' /etc/fstab`.  You typically don't need grep if you're also using awk.  The regex is more complex because I'm filtering out comments, and I have to escape the `/`es since I'm inside a /pattern/.  Anyway, quick one-off scripting stylistic debate aside, df is probably the best recommendation for everyday use.  fstab can have LABEL= as well as UUID=.

Comment: @PeterCordes as I mention in my answer, `fstab` is used to show the _default_ mount point. Of course it's not always up to date, that's the point! As I also explain, I am using the loops to show which of the partitions in `/dev` has a default mount point. I did it that way because I wanted to include an example that listed those that don't. That and for the sake of readability is why I didn't just use `awk`. We're talking about parsing about a dozen lines of text, for such simple tasks I always choose readability and succinctness over cold efficiency.

Comment: @terdon - *mtab* is for showing *up-to-date* mount points.

Comment: `df --output=source /home/ | tail -n1` is the only option out of all of them that allows you to find which device a sub directory of another mountpoint is in.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mount` command. It also shows options with which the mounting is done.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `df` command.